# How would you implement a sorted list with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

im currently try to figure out how I could implement something like a sorted list which holds data that can be selected by a user.

To make it more clear, i have a set of colors and each color can be linked to one or more products. But i don't wont to display the colors sorted by name or hex code. Instead i would give the "admin" the possibility to arrange the order of the colors by himself. Currently i use an additional position attribute for sorting, but it doesn't feel right to me.

Does anybody have done something like this with the entity framework?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a persistent sorting, store a priority column in Colors table or in an attached table (with Colors 1 <-- 0..1 ColorsPriority relationship) and use it for sorting.

You can either use [LINQ's sortby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246669/sort-by-search-criteria-c-linq) or define an [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) that uses the Priority property.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you are right, you can have:

```
public class MyColor
{
    public string name;
    public string hexCode;
    public int sortIndex; //Call it whatever you like

    //Other code...
}
```

So the sortIndex can be set by the admin (rearange the colors), and you can sort by it.